# Method that outputs hash value

Tags: ruby

Say I have two hashes that share one key (for example "foo") but different values. Now I want to create a method with one attribute that puts out the value of the key depending on which hash I chose as attribute. How do I do that?

I have tried:

```
def put_hash(hash)
   puts hash("foo")
end
```

but when I call this function with a hash it gives me the error below:

```
undefined method `hash' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the value with `[]`:

```
puts hash["foo"]
```

Otherwise Ruby thinks you're trying to invoke a method with `()`, and you're seeing an error because there is no method called `hash` in that scope.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
def put_hash(hash)
   puts hash["foo"]
end
```

Or better yet:

```
def put_hash(hash)
   puts hash[:foo]
end
```

Ruby stores the values in a hash like this:

```
{ :foo => "bar" }
```

or

```
 { "foo" => "bar" }
```

Depending if you use a `Symbol` or a `String`

To access them you need to call the `[]` method in the `Hash class`

[The Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) are always a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as

```
def put_hash(hash)
   puts hash["foo"]
end
h1 = { "foo" => 1 }
h2 = { "foo" => 2 }
put_hash(h2) # => 2
```

Look here [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D)

> Element Reference—Retrieves the value object corresponding to the key object